# Ajax Codeigniter variable problem

Tags: variables, codeigniter, post, jquery, loss

I have a question, and I don't know if I'm posting it on the right place of the forum.
I'm trying to do a form with Ajax to count my clicks through Ajax. But the problem is that every time I do a click I always receive the number of clicks as 1.

Here's a piece of the code explained:

**In JavaScript from the View**

```
$("#click").click(function(){    
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: bseUrl+"counter/incCount",
                data: click,
                success: function(html){
                    alert(html);
                }
            });
        });
```

The alert(html) should show the total clicks from the server;

**counter controller**

```
class Counter extends CI_Controller {

    //put your code here
    var $numClick;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->numClick= 0;
    }

    public function Counter() {
        parent::__construct();
$this->numClick= 0;
    }

    public function incCount() {
        echo $this->numClick++;
    }

public function index() {
        //loadView
    }
}
```

But every time I click I'm always receiving the number of clicks as 1.
Why am I losing the variable content every time? it seems that every time I do a Ajax call I'm starting the variable.

Can you guys help me?

Comment: What is the purpose of all this?

Answer (score 1):

You are re-initializing the counter every time you call click handling function - why?
try doing it this way:

```
//init counter somewhere
var num_clicks= 0;
//increase counter and send request
$("#click").click(function(){
            num_clicks++;
            var click= "numberClick="+num_clicks;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: bseUrl+"counter/incCount",
                data: click,
                success: function(html){
                    alert(html);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Every time you make an ajax call, you're starting new apache process, which starts php, which reads codeigniter, which routes your request, then calls for controller constructor ($this->numClick = 0;), then calls controller method "incCount" (assuming $this->numClick is zero by this time, method makes "echo 1;"). Then JS alerts the response (1).

To solve your problem you need to store value of NumClick somewhere outside of php runtime - in external file or database perhaps. In incCount method you must read numClick from this external source, increment it, save it back and only then echo it.

Comment: Thanks Mate =) I thought about that, the Ajax will probably instantiate the file again, but I was not sure.